# Extract item from list of dictionaries using default values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to use list comprehension on the following list;

```
movie_dicts = [
{'title':'A Boy and His Dog', 'year':1975, 'rating':6.6},
{'title':'Ran', 'year':1985, 'rating': 8.3},
{'year':2010, 'rating':8.0},
{'title':'Scanners', 'year':1981, 'rating': 6.7}
]
```

using my knowledge of list comprehension and dictionaries, I know that

```
title_year = [i['title'] for i in movie_dicts]
print title_year
```

will print a list with movie titles. However as one of movie titles are missing i receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./loadjson.py", line 30, in <module>
    title_year = [i['title'] for i in movie_dicts]
KeyError: 'title'
```

Is there any way of checking if the movie title exists placing a default value in its place if it doesn't?

Comment: Use `.get(key, default_value)` to avoid KeyNotFound errors`title_year = [i.get('title') for i in movie_dicts]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to return a default for missing keys:

```
title_year = [i.get('title', '<untitled>') for i in movie_dicts]
```

This substitutes the string `'<untitled>'` for missing titles. Alternatively, filter out entries without the key (producing a shorter list):

```
title_year = [i['title'] for i in movie_dicts if 'title' in i]
```

Comment: Personally I like the second option a little bit more, since is more explicit when reading through the code

Comment: @jlnabais: it produces different output however; you'll get *fewer items* in the list. It depends entirely on what you are trying to do with the list if that is the better choice.

Comment: Sure,I know I missed the part where he asked for a default value, in that case the better answer was the first solution, rather than the "filtered" version of the dictionaries list.

Comment: Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
title_year = [i.get('title', 'defaultTitle') for i in movie_dicts]
```

It gives you the possibility to specify a default value if the specified key does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for helping out